# Tesseract - Recognizing text problems

Tags: php, ocr, tesseract

I am having problems recognizing text with Tesseract and need some help.

The first is a input that is very fuzzy that does not get recognized:

[image: fuzzytext]

The second is a input that gives a broken result:

[image: texterrors]

Which returns this broken result:

"I CRANKSHAFT FORCES Each time combustion occurs, the for rce deﬂects the crankshaft as it transfers torque to the ou put shaft. This deﬂection occursm ' twow ways, to be edn the shaft sidew ways sand to twist the shaft in torsi SlOn Thec an-k mum. ran ankshaft deﬂections are edirectly related to oper- ating roughness of an einng .When back- and—f forth"

I call the windows exe using this PHP commandline which could perhaps be modified to give better results:

```
$exe = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe';
$image = 'Book.png';
$output = 'Out';
$language = ''; // '-l deu' = German etc

$img = 'Images/' . $image; 

exec("\"$exe\" \"$img\" \"$output\" {$language} ");
```

How can i return the correct results for both images?

Comment: From my experience with tesseract, this is an average result. The slight rotation of the text could cause these problems, have you considered correcting that?

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: I recommend either the phpgd library or Imagick. But the real problem will be detecting the rotation, because I think you want to recognize all sorts of images, not just this one, where you can define the rotation beforehand. Or is it possible for you to define the rotation for each image by hand?

Comment: It would have to be automatically done as the inputs would differ each time. Using another exe commandline app for auto image correction would be possible also as i am using tesseract on windows.

Answer (score 0):

Using ImageMagick and morphology close and open one can improve the first image.

```
convert jrxjek.png -morphology close diamond:1 -morphology open diamond:1 jrxjek_close_open.png
```

[image]

Using one of my bash unix shell scripts with ImageMagick, one can automatically detect the rotation in a text image and deskew/derotate it.

```
textdeskew crankshaft.png crankshaft_textdeskew.png
```

[image]

See my scripts at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.html